# mounting cifs reports "No such file of directory" after kernel update to version 5

Tags: kernel, mount, cifs

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS 
I use a network share hosted by our IT department on a windows server for some backups.
I mount this share via fstab

```
//server.ourdomian.com/md$/dir1/dir2/dir3 /mnt/mymountpoint cifs credentials=/etc/.serviceuser.credentials,uid=1001,gid=1001,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755,vers=2.0 0 0
```

Since I last updated the system via apt upgrade etc., this does not longer work.
The console command corresponding to the above results in the message

> mount error(2): No such file or directory

```
sudo mount -t cifs //server.ourdomain.com/md$/dir1/dir2/dir3 /mnt/mymountpoint -o domain=ourdomain,username=myuser,password=mypassord,uid=1001,gid=1001,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755,vers=2.0
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

On another server running the same ubuntu release which I have not yet updated, the same command and the same fstab entry still work perfectly.

The difference between the servers is the kernel version:
5.0.0-1020-azure has problems mounting the cifs share
4.15.0-64-generic works fine. If I boot the problematic server with 4.15.0-64-generic it works fine again.

What has changed? How do I get it working wit Kernel version 5?

Comment: does the directory /mnt/mymountpoint/ exist?

Comment: yes of course, the mountpoint does exist. As I mentioned, nothing has changed, except I updated the system `sudo apt update` `sudo apt upgrade` `sudo apt dist-upgrade` `sudo reboot`

Comment: I found a difference between the systems:
The system where the mount is NOT working has kernel 5.0.0-1020-azure
The system where the mount is still working has kernel 4.15.0-64-generic